# Step component with arrow button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to build step component with arrow button to scroll through left and right using bulma, angularjs, jquery. My requirement is,

- only five elements will be seen inside the visible part of the component.
- As soon as the element moves in the left arrow it fade out.
- As soon as the element moves out the left arrow it fade in.
- As soon as the element moves in the right arrow it fade out.
- As soon as the element moves out the right arrow it fade in.
- Also, same with the mouse scroll

https://codepen.io/singhrhi/pen/ZEYNWQM

```
    ;'use strict';

    angular.module("app.fcrs")
        .controller("ProjectProgressWorkflowViewController", ["$scope",function($scope) {
            angular.extend($scope, {

                test: function() {
                    // console.log("TEEEST");
                },

                test1: function(){
                    // console.dir($('.left-paddle').position().left);
                    // $('.menu').animate({"scrollLeft": '+=190px'}, 300 );
                    $('.menu').animate({"scrollLeft": '+=200px'}, 300 );
                    // $('.menu').on('scroll', function() {
                    //     // console.log($(this))
                    //     // console.log($(this.children[0]))
                    //     $scope.oscrl($(this.children));
                    // });
                },

                test2: function(){
                    // console.dir($('.right-paddle').position().left);
                    $('.menu').animate({"scrollLeft": '-=200px'}, 300 );
                    // $('.menu').on('scroll', function() {
                    //     // console.log($(this.children))
                    //     $scope.oscrl($(this.children));
                    // });
                }
            });
        }]);

    @media screen and (min-width: 769px), print{
    .steps.is-small:not(.is-vertical) .steps-segment:not(:last-child):after {
        height: .16em;
    }
    }

    .steps.is-hollow .steps-marker, .steps-marker.is-hollow {
        border: .2em solid #23d160;
    }

    .steps-marker{
        margin-right: 11rem;
    }

    .TeSEST{
        background: #23d160;
        width:90px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 1px;
    }

    .TeST{
        background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #dbdbdb, #dbdbdb 10px, transparent 10px, transparent 20px);
        width:84px;
        position: absolute;
        right:0px;
        top:2px;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 769px), print {
    .steps.is-small:not(.is-vertical).has-content-centered .steps-segment:not(:last-child):after {
        left: 55%;
        right: -45%;
    }
    }

    .menu-wrapper {
        padding:4px;
        position: relative;
        max-width: 1100px;
        height: 100px; // hide the scroll bar
        margin: 9em;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
    .menu{
        height: 120px; // hide the scroll bar
        box-sizing: border-box;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        opacity:1;
    }

    .paddles {
    }
    .paddle {
        z-index: 10;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 3em;
    }
    .left-paddle {
        left: 0em;
    }
    .right-paddle {
        right: 0em;
    }
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }

    <div ng-controller="ProjectProgressWorkflowViewController">
        <div class="menu-wrapper">
            <ul class="steps is-small has-content-centered menu">
                     <li class="steps-segment item" id="dd">
                        <hr class="TeSEST"></hr>
                        <a href="#" class="steps-marker has-text-weight-normal" id="ddd">
                            1
                        </a>
                        <div class="steps-content" style="width:16em">
                          <div>Project</div>
                          <div>Establishment</div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                   <li class="steps-segment item">
                        <a href="#" class="steps-marker has-text-weight-normal">2</a>
                        <div class="steps-content" style="width:16em">
                            <div>Functional Design</div>
                            <div>&</div>
                            <div>Master Planning</div>
                        </div>
                   </li>
                    <li class="steps-segment item">
                          <a href="#" class="steps-marker  has-text-weight-normal ">3</a>
                          <div class="steps-content" style="width:16em">
                              <div>Concept Design</div>
                          </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="steps-segment item">
                        <a href="#" class="steps-marker  has-text-weight-normal ">4</a>
                        <div class="steps-content" style="width:16em">

                        <div>Schematic Design</div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="steps-segment item">
                          <a href="#" class="steps-marker  has-text-weight-normal ">5</a>
                          <div class="steps-content" style="width:16em">

                          <div>Detailed Design</div>
                          <div>&</div>
                          <div>Documentation</div>
                          </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="steps-segment item">
                      <a href="#" class="steps-marker  has-text-weight-normal ">6</a>
                      <div class="steps-content" style="width:16em">
                      <div>Construction</div>
                      <div>&</div>
                      <div>Completion</div>
                      </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="steps-segment item">
                        <a href="#" class="steps-marker  has-text-weight-normal ">7</a>
                        <div class="steps-content" style="width:16em">

                        <div>Commissioning</div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                      <li class="steps-segment item">
                        <a href="#" class="steps-marker  has-text-weight-normal ">8</a>
                        <div class="steps-content" style="width:16em">
                        <div>Construction</div>
                          <div>Certification</div>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      <li class="steps-segment item">
                        <a href="#" class="steps-marker  has-text-weight-normal ">9</a>
                        <div class="steps-content" style="width:16em">
                        <div>Handover</div>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      <li id="hey" class="steps-segment is-active is-dashed item">
                        <a href="#" class="steps-marker is-hollow has-text-weight-normal has-text-success ">10</a>
                        <div class="steps-content" style="width:16em">

                        <div>Post Construction </div>
                            <div>& </div>
                          <div>Post Occupation </div>
                                    <div>Evaluation</div>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      <li class="steps-segment item">
                          <a href="#" class="steps-marker is-hollow has-text-weight-normal has-text-grey-light ">11</a>
                          <div class="steps-content" style="width:16em">

                          <div>Financial </div>
                            <div>Completion</div>
                          </div>
                          <hr class="TeST"></hr>
                      </li>
                </ul>
                <button class="button is-rounded left-paddle paddle" ng-click="test1()">
                    <div class="step-scroller-text"><<div>
                </button>

                <button class="button is-rounded right-paddle paddle" ng-click="test2()">
                  <div class="step-scroller-text">><div>
                </button>
          </div>
    </div>
```

I am able to scroll the elements with buttons. However not able to achieve fade in fade out effects.
Please help.
Thanks !!

Comment: You should never, **NEVER**, mix Jquery with angularjs. Choose one or the other.

Comment: Can u pls suggest angular js solution